# interrupt and/or other ressources used by Time functions micros() and delayMicroseconds()

Tags: interrupt, arduino-nano, timers, time, core-libraries

I want to use Arduino Uno (Rev. 3) resp. Arduino Nano for time critical ignition control of a combustion engine. Software is developed under arduino rev. 1.6.2.

The only Arduino system functions i use are micros()  and delayMicroseconds(). I suppose they are implemented by a timer interrupt, which may fire within time critical port polling regions of the program.

What's the maximum runtime for the ISR i have to expect? As long it stays within the range of a few microseconds, say 10 or like, it would be tolerable.

Are there other time ressources used in the background by the arduino system i have to cope with?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [The ISR code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L47-L65).

Here is the obj-dump:

```
000008f6 <__vector_16>:
#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny24__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny44__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny84__)
ISR(TIM0_OVF_vect)
#else
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
#endif
{
 8f6:   1f 92           push    r1
 8f8:   0f 92           push    r0
 8fa:   0f b6           in  r0, 0x3f    ; 63
 8fc:   0f 92           push    r0
 8fe:   11 24           eor r1, r1
 900:   2f 93           push    r18
 902:   3f 93           push    r19
 904:   8f 93           push    r24
 906:   9f 93           push    r25
 908:   af 93           push    r26
 90a:   bf 93           push    r27
    // copy these to local variables so they can be stored in registers
    // (volatile variables must be read from memory on every access)
    unsigned long m = timer0_millis;
 90c:   80 91 a0 01     lds r24, 0x01A0
 910:   90 91 a1 01     lds r25, 0x01A1
 914:   a0 91 a2 01     lds r26, 0x01A2
 918:   b0 91 a3 01     lds r27, 0x01A3
    unsigned char f = timer0_fract;
 91c:   30 91 9f 01     lds r19, 0x019F

    m += MILLIS_INC;
    f += FRACT_INC;
 920:   20 e3           ldi r18, 0x30   ; 48
 922:   23 0f           add r18, r19
    if (f >= FRACT_MAX) {
 924:   2d 37           cpi r18, 0x7D   ; 125
 926:   20 f4           brcc    .+8         ; 0x930 <__stack+0x31>
    // copy these to local variables so they can be stored in registers
    // (volatile variables must be read from memory on every access)
    unsigned long m = timer0_millis;
    unsigned char f = timer0_fract;

    m += MILLIS_INC;
 928:   40 96           adiw    r24, 0x10   ; 16
 92a:   a1 1d           adc r26, r1
 92c:   b1 1d           adc r27, r1
 92e:   05 c0           rjmp    .+10        ; 0x93a <__stack+0x3b>
    f += FRACT_INC;
    if (f >= FRACT_MAX) {
        f -= FRACT_MAX;
 930:   23 eb           ldi r18, 0xB3   ; 179
 932:   23 0f           add r18, r19
        m += 1;
 934:   41 96           adiw    r24, 0x11   ; 17
 936:   a1 1d           adc r26, r1
 938:   b1 1d           adc r27, r1
    }

    timer0_fract = f;
 93a:   20 93 9f 01     sts 0x019F, r18
    timer0_millis = m;
 93e:   80 93 a0 01     sts 0x01A0, r24
 942:   90 93 a1 01     sts 0x01A1, r25
 946:   a0 93 a2 01     sts 0x01A2, r26
 94a:   b0 93 a3 01     sts 0x01A3, r27
    timer0_overflow_count++;
 94e:   80 91 a4 01     lds r24, 0x01A4
 952:   90 91 a5 01     lds r25, 0x01A5
 956:   a0 91 a6 01     lds r26, 0x01A6
 95a:   b0 91 a7 01     lds r27, 0x01A7
 95e:   01 96           adiw    r24, 0x01   ; 1
 960:   a1 1d           adc r26, r1
 962:   b1 1d           adc r27, r1
 964:   80 93 a4 01     sts 0x01A4, r24
 968:   90 93 a5 01     sts 0x01A5, r25
 96c:   a0 93 a6 01     sts 0x01A6, r26
 970:   b0 93 a7 01     sts 0x01A7, r27
}
 974:   bf 91           pop r27
 976:   af 91           pop r26
 978:   9f 91           pop r25
 97a:   8f 91           pop r24
 97c:   3f 91           pop r19
 97e:   2f 91           pop r18
 980:   0f 90           pop r0
 982:   0f be           out 0x3f, r0    ; 63
 984:   0f 90           pop r0
 986:   1f 90           pop r1
 988:   18 95           reti
```

I'll let you calculate how many clock cycles that is. My guess is that it's less that 160 clock cycles (i.e. 10S).

But I'm unsure if the accuracy of `micros` is good enough in your application.